# Exact String value is not matching

Tags: java

I am calling the following in an isolated test.

The output from this method is "50 000".

I have checked and there is no space to trim. (also did try trim just in case).

When I perform a equals check, the test fails saying:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :50 000
Actual   :50 000
```

Why is this the case?

This is my method.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public String aaa() {
    String amt = "50000";
    Locale locale = new Locale("sv","SE");
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
    amt = f.format(Long.parseLong(amt));
    return amt;
}
```

This is my test case.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals("50 000", myClass.aaa());
}
```

What am I missing here? Why are they not equal?

Comment: Puzzling. Different type of whitespace character in the middle perhaps?

Comment: Try to print the code points for each character. I once had a case where some text  contained a different character that just looked the same.

Comment: @Jesper Perhaps delete your comment and paste it into the 'answer' box, because surely there's nothing more to be said here: You got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space that is in the result is not a normal space character, but a non-breaking space character. Try this and see the test succeed:

```
assertEquals("50\u00a0000", myClass.aaa());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the value of the character at position 2 will be 160, when you check the value will find it refers to Non-breaking space

, Also it's a good practice to use `ErrorCollector` for Junit4 or `assertAll` for Junit5 when you assert multiple asserts

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // Arrange
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("50").append((char) 160).append("000");

    // Act
    String actual = myClass.aaa();

    // Assert
    assertEquals(6, actual.length());
    assertEquals(builder.toString(), actual);
}
```